# Date format in JS

Tags: javascript

When I do new Date() in JS I get:

```
Thu Jul 26 2018 08:09:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

How can I get it in this format along with the included Z at the end?

```
2016-05-26t16:53:22.313Z
```

Comment: Did you mean to have a lowercase "t" in your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are other answers available, I recently found that you can call `toJSON()` on the date object to get the ISO formatted string:

```js
console.log((new Date()).toJSON());
```

Comment: I'd prefer `Date.prototype.toISOString()` as it's quite explicit. The exact implementation of `toJSON()` could change in future

Comment: @Phil -- thank you for your comment. I didn't find anything such on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON). Do you have some references handy?

Comment: It's right there in the link you provided ~ _"Calling `toJSON()` returns a string (using `toISOString()`) representing the Date object's value."_. If you want an ISO string, you should probably call `toISOString`. At the moment, it's only an implementation detail that means both methods produce the same result

Comment: @Phil -- Right. Wanted a reference for the phrase _could change in future_ in your first comment.

Comment: There's nothing saying it won't either :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to get this:

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```